# Thread synchronization with MPI

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi

I am trying to use threads with MPI. This program spawns a thread for rank = 0 and sends and receives messages (blocking) to and from the threads. The number of threads is command line input. This code however blocks on the sends/receives, any ideas on how to fix this? Also, the thread level safety I receive is MPI_THREAD_SINGLE, not what I ask for MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE. Doesnt _SINGLE really mean there can be only one thread that is executed per process? Why then does the output with more than one thread shows both the threads received the message?

Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
       int id;
} struct_t;

void *getmsg(void *arg)
{
    int rank;
    char mystr[10];
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status status;
    struct_t *fd=(struct_t *)arg;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    printf("Rank %d is waiting in thread %d for my message\n", rank, fd->id);
    while(1){
            MPI_Recv(mystr, 10, MPI_CHAR, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            if(status.MPI_TAG == 0){
                    printf("Thread %d on rank %d received NULL from %d\n", fd->id, rank, status.MPI_SOURCE);
                    return;
            }
            printf("Thread %d on rank %d received %s from rank %d\n", fd->id, rank, mystr, status.MPI_SOURCE);
    }
    printf("I am now sending the string to rank 1\n");
    MPI_Send(mystr, 10, MPI_CHAR, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    return (NULL);
}

void spawn_thread(int n)
{
    int rank, i;
    pthread_t *threads;
    pthread_attr_t pthread_custom_attr;
    struct_t *fd;
    threads=(pthread_t *)malloc(n*sizeof(threads));
    fd=(struct_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct_t)*n);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            fd[i].id=i;
     //       printf("My rank is %d and I created thread #%d\n", rank, i);
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getmsg, (void *)(fd+i));
    }

    free(fd);
}

void main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int n,i, provided, claimed;
    int rank, size, errs;

    int main;

    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    char mystr[10];
    MPI_Status status;

    if(rank==0 && provided<MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE){
            printf("You get %d level thread safety, not %d\n",provided, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE);
    }
    if (argc != 2)
    {
            printf ("Usage: %s n\n  where n is no. of threads\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }

    n=atoi(argv[1]);
    if ((n < 1) || (n > MAX_THREAD))
    {
            printf ("The no of thread should between 1 and %d.\n",MAX_THREAD);
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,-1);
 }

    MPI_Request request;
    if(rank == 0){
            spawn_thread(n);
    }

    printf("Rank %d says hello\n",rank);
    MPI_Send("HELLO!!!", 10, MPI_CHAR, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("Rank %d is sending Null\n",rank);
    if(rank==0)
            MPI_Send(NULL,0,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Recv(mystr, 10, MPI_CHAR, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("I am rank %d and I received %s \n",rank, mystr);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you launch the program together with the output you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

The provided MPI thread level support is not the one you ask because your MPI library wasn't compiled and install with it. The provided support value is what your library can gives you and not necessary what you are asking. So this value is not always equal or greather than the required value. 
For example, for OpenMPI, you have to configure it with the option --enable-mpi-thread-multiple

You can check it with this command:

```
shell$ ompi_info | grep -i thread
      Thread support: posix (mpi: yes, progress: no)
```

If it says mpi: no, you have no chance to have multi thread support

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you are running this program, but I'm assuming your running with multiple processes and creating multiple threads. With that being said, your issue is with this line:

```
  MPI_Send("HELLO!!!", 10, MPI_CHAR, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The reason it is blocking is because the way you have it setup, Process 0 is sending a message to itself, and so it will wait for itself to recv the message, which turns into a never-ending waiting game.

Try and rework your code, making sure your sending/receiving to/from the right places, and if you have anymore issues, let us know.